# a python question about list, append and mutability

Tags: python, list, mutability

Here is my code:

```
list1 = ["dog", "cat"]
list2 = list1 
list2.append ("fish") 
print(list1)
print(list2)  # both list1 and list2 will be [“dog”, “cat”, “fish”].
```

I do understand why `print(list1)`>>> `[“dog”, “cat”, “fish”]`.

But I do not understand why `print(list2)`>>> `[“dog”, “cat”, “fish”]`.

Could someone explain it please?

Comment: Because `list1 is list2`, that is, you now have two different variables referencing the same object. `list1 = list2` *does not copy anything*

Comment: Some super helpful reading: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html